# What are Towsend Coeffiecents exactly? And are there any tables out there to look them up?

Tags: electromagnetism, atomic-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, classical-electrodynamics

My question is expecially for the gamma coefficent, does it depend from the air?
And further how the material of electrodes is involved in Paschen's Law (Electric Arcs)?

Comment: Have a look at these topics via wikipedia first- then check in with me here if you have any unresolved questions afterwards. -NN

Comment: Okay I have looked it up and found out that gamma describes the average number of electrones emitted by the collision of the iones with the cathode, so this coefficent is depending on the material of cathode and the type of element the iones are of. But I dont know how to calculate this value for iron and average iones which are created by air-ionization.

Comment: in general, those things cannot be calculated- they have to be measured experimentally.

Comment: Okay, so this should have been listed in some books or websites. Do you or anyone know where?

Comment: I worked in this field in 1976-79 so all my references are probably out of date.